# Boostrap 3.1.1 - CSS not kicking for IE9

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I've read the posts regarding Bootstrap 3 and IE 9, however none of the responses seemed to apply or work.

We're working on a dev site with Bootstrap and for some reason the CSS doesn't get applied when viewing in IE9. I've got the right doctype, etc. So I'm puzzled why this is happening.

Can someone take a look and offer advice?

Here's the URL : [ REDACTED - no longer necessary ]

Comment: I cleaned up all the HTML validation problems. Still not working.

Comment: Fixed. I had this in the head section:

`<!--[if IE 10]> <style> (snipped </style> -->`

And for some reason IE9 freaks out. No matter, IE 10 doesn't read conditional statements as did previous regurgitations of IE, so I switched this something like this:

`html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] h1 { font-size: 20px }`